# Regular Expression to match a string only when certain characters don't exist

Tags: python, regex, url

So, here's my question:

I have a crawler that goes and downloads web pages and strips those of URLs (for future crawling).  My crawler operates from a whitelist of URLs which are specified in regular expressions, so they're along the lines of:

```
(http://www.example.com/subdirectory/)(.*?)
```

...which would allow URLs that followed the pattern to be crawled in the future.  The problem I'm having is that I'd like to exclude certain characters in URLs, so that (for example) addresses such as:

```
(http://www.example.com/subdirectory/)(somepage?param=1¶m=5#print)
```

...in the case above, as an example, I'd like to be able to exclude URLs that feature ?, #, and = (to avoid crawling those pages).  I've tried quite a few different approaches, but I can't seem to get it right:

```
(http://www.example.com/)([^=\?#](.*?))
```

etc.  Any help would be really appreciated!

EDIT:  sorry, should've mentioned this is written in Python, and I'm normally fairly proficient at regex (although this has me stumped)

EDIT 2:  VoDurden's answer (the accepted one below) almost yields the correct result, all it needs is the $ character at the end of the expression and it works perfectly - example:

```
(http://www.example.com/)([^=\?#]*)$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This expression should be what you're looking for:

```
(http://www.example.com/subdirectory/)([^=?#]*)$
```

[^=\?#] Will match anything except for the characters you specified.

For Example:

- http://www.example.com/subdirectory/ **Match**
- http://www.example.com/subdirectory/index.php **Match**
- http://www.example.com/subdirectory/somepage?param=1&param=5#print **No Match**
- http://www.example.com/subdirectory/index.php?param=1 **No Match**

Comment: Your method almost worked - I tried it and it seemed not to work, so I added $ to the end, and it seems to work (it'll need more testing, but your method has just saved me a lot of time!):

(http://www.example.com/subdirectory/)([^=\?#]*)$

Comment: Updated the answer with the trailing $. Make sure to leave a comment if you find any other problems during testing :)

Answer (score 1):

```
(http://www.example.com/)([^=?#]*?)
```

Should do it, this will allow any URL that does not contain the characters you don't want.

It might however be a little bit hard to extend this approach. A better option is to have the system work two-tiered, i.e. one set of matching regex, and one set of blocking regex. Then only URL:s which pass both of these will be allowed. I think this solution will be a bit more transparent and flexible.

Comment: I never thought of it like that, I'll give that a go

Comment: If you do, please accept/upvote, otherwise you'll have a neverending army of regexers aswering the question =).

Comment: The backslash is not necessary inside the character class.

Comment: Your method almost worked, just needed a $ on the end (outside the parenthesis)!  It yields the same results as VoDurden's method (which is the same except for the missing ?).  I've updated the question with the answer and accepted VoDurden's as the correct one (because I read it first)

Thanks very much everyone!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to crawl the pages upto `?param=1&param=5`

because normally param=1 and param=2 could give you completely different web page.

pick up one the wordpress website to confirm that.

Try like this one, It will try to match just before # char

```
(http://www.example.com/)([^#]*?)
```

Comment: Yep, the site that I'm crawling uses parameters, but these don't provide any difference in the content of the pages so it would be a waste for both myself and their website if I crawled it (which is why I want to exclude URLs that contain parameters and #)

Comment: ok, if you really really sure that you dont need those parts after ?=# , use like others peeople suggest, ([^=\?#]*?), and vote up / accept answers to other people reply, cheers! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of what you want. If you wan't to match anything that doesn't containst any ?, #, and = then the regex is

```
([^=?#]*)
```

Comment: You can drop the backslash - inside the character class, the ? is not a special character.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative there's always the urlparse module which is designed for parsing urls.

```
from urlparse import urlparse

urls= [
    'http://www.example.com/subdirectory/',
    'http://www.example.com/subdirectory/index.php',
    'http://www.example.com/subdirectory/somepage?param=1&param=5#print',
    'http://www.example.com/subdirectory/index.php?param=1',
]

for url in urls:
    # in python 2.5+ you can use urlparse(url).query instead
    if not urlparse(url)[4]:
        print url
```

Provides the following:

```
http://www.example.com/subdirectory/
http://www.example.com/subdirectory/index.php
```